# Qt crashes when running a basic OpenCV command VideoCapture

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, mingw, video-capture

I have an interesting problem when i switched to OpenCV 4.3.0 version.
I built OpenCV 4.3.0 with Qt using Cmake 3.16.0 and mingw730_64 and build done in Release mode on Windows 10 machine

When i compile a simple code including VideoCapture, i can build it without errors but when i run it in Release mode exe simply crashes..

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>

..
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
..
    VideoCapture capWebcam(0);
..
}
```

There is no problem when reading and displaying images..!

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Mat Test_Image;

    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open Image File", QDir::currentPath(), "Image (*.*)");


    if(QFile::exists(fileName))
    {

        Test_Image = imread(fileName.toStdString(), IMREAD_COLOR);


        if(Test_Image.empty()){
            QMessageBox msg;
            msg.setText("File couldn't load!");
            msg.exec();
        }
        else {
            namedWindow("Test Window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
            flip(Test_Image, Test_Image,0);
            cvtColor(Test_Image, Test_Image, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            imshow("Test Window", Test_Image);
            waitKey(1);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me understand why the program crashes immediately when i instantiate VideoCapture object?

```
C:\Qt_Projects\build-Deneme1-Desktop_Qt_5_14_2_MinGW_64_bit-Release\release\Deneme1.exe crashed.
```

Thank you in advance.